# How to use webstorm with codeship?

Tags: webstorm

Is it possible to use webstorm with codeship? Currently I can connect with github and bitbucket only.

If not can I get steps to work with a codeship repo?

Comment: It's a user question about webstorm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm mistaken, but [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) is a cross platform IDE and doesn't limit where you can host your source code. If they provide a SCM hosting platform as well you wouldn't be able to use it with Codeship.

For using Codeship you need to host your repository with either GitHub or BitBucket. (Though we may add new providers in the future.)

~ Marko (a software engineer at Codeship)